# How to speed up reading in multiple R objects with parLapply?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rdata

I have lots of big lists which I saved (unfortunately at the time) as `.RData` files. All files had the same name when saving them. Hence, after reading in the files, I want to assign them a new name. I want to speed up this process and thought about parallel computing. My try was (assuming the file names only differ with the last character of their name):

```
require(parallel)
myReadin <- function (x) {
  # Lets assume all lists were named myList when saving them and are hence returned with that name
  load(paste0('myFolder/list', x, '.RData'))
  assign(paste0('myList', x), myList, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
cl <- makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", detectCores()))
call.function <- parLapply(cl, 1:50, myReadin)
```

This generally works. However, when reading in the files, my computers CPU is not maxed out but it seems like the computer is only using one core. Furthermore, only one list `call.function` with the 50 different lists is returned  but not 50 single lists (`myList1, ..., myList50`) are in the global environment.
Is there a way to use all my cores to read in the different files and have them all as single lists in the global environment?

Comment: You cannot do tasks with side effects (like assigning into the global environment) in parallel. The parallel workers don't have access to the global environment. Your `myReadin` function should return the list, so that `parLapply` can return a list of your lists. That's much more useful than a bunch of related objects free-floating in the global environment anyway.

Comment: Thanks @Roland for the answer. When I am running my code, my computers CPU is not maxed but seems like only using one core. Is that a general problem of trying to parallelize loading of R objects or is my code wrong?

Comment: You are reading files. This might not be processor limited but I/O limited.